# xcode11 - Requesting Authorization for Location Services in ios 13

Tags: ios, xcode, geolocation

I would like to requests the user’s permission to use location services while using the app, Allow Once or Don't allow.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nmbvu.jpg)

I only have code in ViewController.swift because I build the app with Ruby on Rails.

Which property list key I should use and how?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `locationManager` for this:

```
locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
```

To request "always" location access as well as:

```
 locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
```

Comment: Hey Daniil, I'm a newbie in xcode, Would you share how do you implement your solution?

Comment: @NovaTogatorop Have you checked [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620551-requestalwaysauthorization)?

Comment: Yes, but I'm still a bit lost.